# Type Timestamp and UTC

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql database. In a column, I set Structure Type timestamp. I need that column to know at what day and hour the user updated their information. But I realize the database store the time zone from where I am (Europe) that is UTC+2. That could cause problems with users in different time zones. It would be better to store a universal time, that is UTC.

Can MySql automatically register the timestamp UTC?

I can change the column type from timestamp to date. Each time that the user updates his information I can get the UTC and update that information manually.

```
$utc = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

So, I can update the UTC time every time I make an update. But I was expecting that MySql would provide a column type that could do that automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: Mysql has `default-time-zone`, make the UTC. `gmdate` is going to be the time the server has though, not the client's timezone, right?

Comment: I do not understand, where do you put that default-time-zone? In PhpMyAdmin Structure I do not have that option

Comment: If I understand, gmdate gives the UTC, that is the universal time anywhere in the world. Am I wrong?

Comment: That is based on your servers clock though, not the clients timezone. `$utc = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");` I suspect will be the same for a request from new york and california. Nothing in that is importing user data.